# web part uses default values instead of new value from propertypanetextfield

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, web-part-property

I am using a react web part. I don't understand why my web part is using the default value instead of updated value from the propertyPanetext field. Isn't this behavior supposed to be reactive. There is no onchange method by default for the propertyPanetextField.

Comment: Yes, it should change.Two type of Property Pane is available , once is reactive and other is non-reactive.Non-reactive comes with an Apply button. just wantted to understand once you change the Text value in Property Pane and close the pane whether that value reatined for future. Please check webpart data also in the page source.

Comment: @vinitkumar it doesn't retain the value. but if i refresh the page it will use the value in the propertypanetextfield.I do think that the rerendering is not working here

Comment: any React Render issue in Developer Tools, may be need to debug only more, because there is no way it should not work.

Comment: @vinitkumar this is the sample am using https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-file-upload/src/webparts/fileUpload